# Out of bound of array error while creating Database Diagram SQL Server 2017

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, database-diagram

I am using SSMS 2017 and my database is SQL Server 2016 Enterprise. An error is being shown while creating a database diagram:

> The index is out of bound of array

How to resolve it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself by Creating database diagram in SSMS 2016, turns out you can create Database diagrams in their own/same version browsers. Thanks anyways

Like 
if your SQL SERVER database engine is of 2016
you need to also use SSMS of 2016 to create its database diagram.

Answer (score 11):

As workaround, try starting SSMS as Administrator.

Comment: I always run ssms as administrator, please suggest anything else.